# how to group java log entries?

Tags: java, logging

I would like to group my java log entries for searching among them more easily.
I mean there are the next log records:

```
14-Mar-2012 14:29:07 com.acme.service.AcmeService log
INFO: Start ACME operation
14-Mar-2012 14:29:07 com.acme.service.AcmeService log
INFO: step 1 - do something
...
14-Mar-2012 14:29:07 com.acme.service.AcmeService log
INFO: End ACME operation
```

These records belong to each other as these are the steps of a workflow (e.g. I would like to track a process of a webservice).
Is there a good design pattern for holding together these records that I will be able to find the logs of a webservice request easily? (e.g. to put in the beginning of all the log entries an ID)?
Is there a tool which could display these logs by grouping them automatically? like log4j chainsaw but grouping together by this id?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you extend Level and add your own custom level(s). All your webservice logging could be done at that level.

Once you have your own level you can customize how it is logged including logging to different file etc

Comment: Hi bluesman, thanks! I have never extended the Log class, won't it spoil my log files by this?
Do you think whether is there any GUI tools for displaying nicely these grouped logs? For example: INFO AcmeService 384d63gd33 + (the weird number wants to be the identifier) And to click to the sign + we will get all the logs which belong to the given requests.

Comment: It won't spoil your log files.
I'm not aware of GUI tools for grouping logs, but if you want to search for something particular through your logs and show them together you can use grep (linux environment or using git bash on windows)

Comment: Thanks again! My problem is that I have to log data which consist of more rows (e.g. SOAP requests) and this data belongs to a log entry so I have to handle and display them together... I don't know how I could do this with grep. And I don't know either as I am not a big Linux expert. :)

Answer (score 4):

Are you using sessions in your webapp? If so, you could use the session ID to differentiate between requests.

Sorry, just realised from looking at your example that I think you're using java.util.Logging. The below will only work for log4j. I'm now curious to see if anyone has a fix cos I'd like to know as well. In my experience with both, I've found log4j to be much, much easier to use and configure.

**Log4j solution**

Pass all of the requests through a filter and then use `NDC.push( id )`. Then use `%x` in your pattern for output to the file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately we have to use java.util.Logging... :( Do you think whether is there any GUI tools for displaying nicely these grouped logs?
For example: INFO AcmeService 384d63gd33 +
(the weird number wants to be the identifier) And to click to the sign + we will get all the logs which belong to the given requests. Or am I too idealistic? :)

Comment: There might well be a tool to do that, but I don't know of one, sorry. I need to have another crack at identifiers in j.u.l. myself at some point so I'll report back if I have any success.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am thinking of using ThreadLocal to put information into the log header so I could implement a solution which is similar to NDC.push().

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in Spring technologies, you can easily configure a Spring Integration module to receive the logs in a channel, split them by type using a router and save them into a database using an outbound adapter. A lot of wiring comes out of box, you need to do only  minimal coding.

http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration#documentation

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will check it but unfortunately I am not working in Spring environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chainsaw to parse a regular text log file, regardless of what logging API was used to create it.  See the LogFilePatternReceiver example in the example receiver config xml available from the Welcome tab.

In your example, once you include the session in your log file output, you can add the session as a property, and then colorize/sort and filter using the session.  You could also use that session ID as the 'logger' and get the benefit of the logger tree's ability to focus on individual loggers, essentially giving you your 'grouping' behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My problem is that I have got multi-line log entries as well so I could handle the log entries (and the rows in the log files) as a record. I think the command agrep will suit me. I am using java.util logging.

Comment: It looks like this is a common layout for java.util.logging.  I'll update the LogFilePatternReceiver to support multiple lines in the log format.